# Normalization-by-evaluation for untyped lambda calculus which results in -normal form

Tags: algorithms, lambda-calculus, functional-programming, normal-forms

Usual NbE algorithms for untyped lambda calculus, which use (P)HOAS to embed terms to a host language constructs, results in a beta-normal form of a terms.

Is there algorithms to (efficiently) exploit host language constructs to normalize untyped terms to beta-eta normal form?

Comment: Usually, NbE results in $\beta$-normal *$\eta$-long* normal forms! Can you cite your source for the first claim?

Comment: @cody I don't know. Does it holds for untyped lambda calculus too?

Comment: @cody I edited the question to mention untyped LC

Comment: All normalization algorithms exploit host language constructs. More specifically, do you mean algorithms which use eta conversion in the host language?